# PhoneGap Build doesn't update the app

Tags: phonegap-build

PhoneGap Build shows successful build and log for Android, shows updated version on the PhoneGap Build web page, but when I install Android shows old version and the APK file is also old. I know for sure because I just put 2Mb of dummy images and the sise of the APK hasn't changed, so the problem is with build

Edit: it was a 1-day glitch, it works OK now

Comment: Are you definitely downloading and installing the correct apk?

Comment: yes. The problem is obvious - the www.zip is 5 Mb because I put 1Mb of additional images there and apk is 4 Mb like the old version.

Comment: Ah, you're uploading it as a zip. My experience with is has been to pull my app from GitHub. I've used it a lot. Have you tried deleting your app and starting from scratch?

Comment: OK it was a daily  glitch. It all works as before now - resolved.

Comment: I have that from time to time. Sometimes simply clicking the "Rebuild" button fixes the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we see this problem every now and then. Our solution to it is to remove and ad back in the affected platform. Assuming you are also using the latest cordova tools do the following:

```
cordova platform remove android
cordova platform add android
```

Comment: it would be awesome if we can do it in one line like 

cordova platform reinstall android <= will do remove and add on android